# Visual Studio Load Test results database

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to set up a load test in visual studio, however whenever I run it I get the error:

"Could not connect to Load Test Results Database".

I click the link for help with the error and it takes me to a page to install SQL Server, However I was under the impression this could be stored locally without SQL Server. Any Ideas on how to set it up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to setup your SQL for load tests. From  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/06/04/getting-started-with-load-testing-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx

> Fortunately this is quite easy to fix….Navigate to the IDE directory were you installed Visual Studio 2012 and open the file: loadtestresultsrepository.sql.
>
> Right clicking anywhere in this file and choosing “Execute” will prompt you for the location of the SQL Server you want to store the results.
>
> NOTE if you are installing the database using SQL Integrated Security you will want to run Visual Studio as an Administrator.